# day and time dimension in star schema

Tags: ssas, tabular, dimensional-modeling

Is it best practice to separate datetime into two dimensions: day and UTCtime especially in the context of tabular models? Google did not provide much information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data set you are analyzing, if you want to analyse on hour or minute it is better for performance to separate the dimensions. This would require Using a datekey and timekey for your fact tables.